# Key column not displayed despite ScaffoldColumn(true)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, data-annotations

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC 3 project using EF CodeFirst. I have a simple class with few attributes set on key column:

```
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
    public short TagID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see there are DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None) and ScaffoldColumn(true) attributes. That's because I want to be able to enter the TagID manually. Now when TagControler is added to the project I don't have the TagID column shown in neither of 5 generated views.

I know I can add it manually, but I wonder if this behavior is by design or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primary keys aren't scaffolded as editable fields by default. Instead there is a hidden field for the key. If you wanted to change this behavior you could modify the templates but it is by design since generally it doesn't make sense to edit the primary key of an entity.

Here is some info on how to do this if you wanted to make this change any time you added a view or wanted to make some other custom change to the scaffolding:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joecar/archive/2011/01/06/add-the-asp-net-mvc-3-code-templates-to-your-application-with-nuget.aspx

Comment: I agree that it doesn't make sense to edit the primary key of an entity, but it certainly makes sense to enter it manually on creation. IMHO only difference between primary key field that is not auto-generated by database and any other editable field should be only in Edit view, where primary key field should be displayed as read only.